# How to Post data from ajax get by post not working in postman?

Tags: magento2.3.1, post-data

Below is my code when I try to post data  but not working

URL is

> http://localhost/test1/modulename/login/request

my ajax code for javascript

```
var request_data = 'id='+id+'&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&social_type='+social_type;

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
         var url = data.redirect;
         if(url!=''){
            window.location.href = data.redirect;
        }
     }
 };
xhttp.open("POST", window.request_url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.send(request_data);
```

Below is my controller code,

```
<?php
namespace Lucent\SocialLogin\Controller\Login;
```

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

```
protected $_customer;
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->data = $_REQUEST;
    print_r($this->data);
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
}


public function execute()
{
    print_r($this->data);
    echo '1';
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    print_r($post);
    die();

}
```

}

So please help me. thanks

I updated by exact controller code so hope not it will help you to solve it.

Comment: what error you are facing?

Comment: not going in  execute() function even and when i open in browser then it works well.

Comment: share your ajax code, also share screenshot of error

Comment: please check i update my code

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: no mate , i didnt got.

Comment: remove all code in execute method and simply put die and check whether it is coming inside that function..

Comment: not coming whenever i tried with post method in postman but coming with get method . so i want with post method

Answer (score 1):

Please **die in construct and print all the parameters**, and check you are posting form key or not.

Without it, you cannot get data to execute a function. And use the following method for getting parameters.

```
$params = $this->getReqest()->getPost();
```

Comment: i will share ajax and controller code ok

Comment: var request_data = 'variable pass';
          
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                var url = data.redirect;
                if(url!=''){
                  window.location.href = data.redirect;
                }
            }
          };
          xhttp.open("GET", window.request_url, true);
          xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.send(request_data);

Comment: namespace Lucent\SocialLogin\Controller\Login;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
class Request extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
  )
  {
    return parent::__construct($context);
  }


  public function execute()
  {
    $data = array();
    $data['redirect'] = '';

Comment: Post your code like you did with controller , such that it will be easy to debug..

Comment: check updated exact my code so you will get some ideas!

Comment: i tried in construct and ther i got post data but then in execute function not get that data. help me

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution here. When I trying with $.post() method that time no need of form_key.

But, When I trying with var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); with post method then form_key mandatory so that is why $_POST data not getting so quit from it.

Thanks all whoever supports.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add below code in controller.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Display extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
  {
    return parent::__construct($context);
  }

  public function execute()
  {

        $posts = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        print_r($posts);

  }

}
?>
```